# Warning: Undefined variable $g_fonts in

Tags: wordpress

Jevelin theme error.
Maeby somebody can help with this error.
[theme error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJNvA.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhMeV.png)

public function get_google_font( $font ) {
$fonts = $this->get_fonts();

```
        foreach ( $fonts['google']['items'] as $g_font ) {
            if ( $font === $g_font['family'] ) {
                return $g_font;
            }
        }
    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the $fonts variable is empty. Could you try to do this:

```
public function get_google_font($font) {

    $fonts = $this->get_fonts();

    if (!empty($fonts)) {
        foreach ($fonts['google']['items'] as $g_font) {
            if ($font === $g_font['family']) {
                return $g_font;
            }
        }
    }
}
```